# ¿Por qué se cambian los datos al hacer SELECT SUM de dos tablas?

Tags: mysql, sql

tengo la siguiente consulta pero los datos de la suma del Total_OTServicioTecnico es distinta al que me marca en la base de datos, ¿A qué se debe eso?.

```
SELECT MONTH(Fecha_OTServicioTecnico) as mes, SUM(Total_OTServicioTecnico) as monto, MONTH(Fecha_OTPloteo) as mes2, SUM(Total_OTPloteo) as montos
FROM `ot_servicio_tecnico`, `ot_ploteo`
WHERE `Fecha_OTServicioTecnico` >= '2020-01-01'
AND `Fecha_OTServicioTecnico` <= '2020-12-31'
AND `Fecha_OTPloteo` >= '2020-01-01'
AND `Fecha_OTPloteo` <= '2020-12-31'
GROUP BY `mes`
ORDER BY `mes`
```

**Estas son mis tablas en la base de datos**

[image: Esta es mi tabla de servicio tecnico]

[image: Esta es mi tabla de ploteo]

**Pero el resultado que recibo es el siguiente**

[image: Ejecución de la consulta]

Comment: En general es mejor utilizar `INNER JOIN`, `LEFT JOIN`, `RIGHT JOIN`, etc en lugar de la forma que estas utilizando. También por favor coloca el resultado que esperas obtener. Saludos.